# Import and use authenticated SAP WSDLs with Eclipse/Maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, soap, wsdl, sap-erp

I have an **ASP.NET (C#) project** that is based on consuming SOAP services from the german SAP ERP and we recently decided to port it to a **Java dynamic web project**. Mostly of all these web services needs authentication.

On **Visual Studio** (ASP.NET), though, it was pretty easy and straightforward to import a web service, as easy as clicking on `Add service reference`, putting the *WSDL URL*, giving a *namespace* name and clicking on `Ok`. Done. All the generated classes will be "hidden" just so someone wouldnt change then. Nice! Also, we have a bindings file, which is plain XML, containing stuff like `maxBufferSize`, `maxBufferPoolSize`, `maxReceivedMessageSize` etc...

On **Eclipse** (Java), I tried adding a `New` Web Service Client (New > Web Services > Web Service Client) and this is where I faced my first problem. It is like it does **not recognize the WSDL as a valid URL** for some reason, however **it works in any browser** (it even prompts for the authentication) and **also in the Visual Studio** project. This is what the WSDL look like: http://spceqsap01:8000/sap/bc/srt/wsdl/flv_10002A111AD1/bndg_url/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/zws_listar_municipios/300/zws_listar_municipios/zws_listar_municipios?sap-client=300
There are a few WSDLs out there used in examples and they are "successfully" imported, except that the Eclipse complains about some JARs. One curious thing that I noted is that most of them ends with `?wsdl`, but placing this in the above WSDL wont work.

*Maven* has a few plugins to generate the source code for the WSDLs, but I couldnt get it to work too (sources weren't generated or anything, probably because missing some plugin configuration or wrong ones). If someone has a working example for consuming SAP web services, please post below!

For the Java dynamic web project, we're currently using the following:

- Maven 3.3.9
- Java 8
- Tomcat 9
- VRaptor 4.2
- Hibernate 5.2.9
- Eclipse Neon 4.6.1

This is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <!-- Artifact details -->
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>br.com.nooder</groupId>
    <artifactId>portal</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <!-- Properties -->
    <properties>
        <deploy.version.log4j>2.8.2</deploy.version.log4j>
        <deploy.version.vraptor>4.2.0-RC5</deploy.version.vraptor>
        <deploy.version.weld>3.0.0.CR2</deploy.version.weld>
        <deploy.version.hibernate>5.2.9.Final</deploy.version.hibernate>
        <deploy.version.junit>4.12</deploy.version.junit>
        <deploy.version.slf4j>1.7.25</deploy.version.slf4j>
    </properties>

    <!-- Development and production settings -->
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>tst</id>
            <properties>
                <deploy.enviroment>tst</deploy.enviroment>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prd</id>
            <properties>
                <deploy.enviroment>prd</deploy.enviroment>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <!-- Dependencies -->
    <dependencies>
        <!-- JUnit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${deploy.version.junit}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- VRaptor -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.com.caelum</groupId>
            <artifactId>vraptor</artifactId>
            <version>${deploy.version.vraptor}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- VRaptor plugins -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.com.caelum.vraptor</groupId>
            <artifactId>vraptor-java8</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.com.caelum.vraptor</groupId>
            <artifactId>vraptor-brutauth</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.com.caelum.vraptor</groupId>
            <artifactId>vraptor-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.com.caelum.vraptor</groupId>
            <artifactId>vraptor-hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        -->

        <!-- VRaptor's dependencies: Servlet Container (Tomcat) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>${deploy.version.weld}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                  <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.el</groupId>
                  <artifactId>jboss-el-api_3.0_spec</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-core-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${deploy.version.weld}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                  <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.el</groupId>
                  <artifactId>jboss-el-api_3.0_spec</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- VRaptor's dependencies: Java 8 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.18.1-GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- VRaptor's dependencies: Bean Validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator-cdi</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate + DB -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${deploy.version.hibernate}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JavaEE 8: CDI -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Tomcat's dependencies: JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Maven's dependencies (?) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Expression language -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Log4j 2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${deploy.version.log4j}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${deploy.version.log4j}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${deploy.version.log4j}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${deploy.version.slf4j}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!-- Build -->
    <build>
        <finalName>portal</finalName>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>

        <!-- Resources -->
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <filters>
            <filter>src/main/filters/settings.${deploy.enviroment}.properties</filter>
        </filters>

        <plugins>
            <!-- JDK Compiler Level -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-parameters</compilerArgument>
                    <testCompilerArgument>-parameters</testCompilerArgument>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Eclipse project -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Always download and attach dependencies source code -->
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                    <!-- Avoid type mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0 -->
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- For Maven Tomcat Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <path>/portal</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Any input is **GREATLY** appreciated!

Comment: Don't use the `maven-eclipse-plugin`. It is deprecated and will break your Maven/Eclipse integration. (off topic I know)

Comment: Thank you, Steve. Like I said, any input is greatly appreciated. I used to work with Java and Maven in the past, so I'm still kinda rusty and this was taken from the mkyong guy's site. Could you elaborate on this, though?

Comment: Basically it predates the current maven/eclipse (m2e) integration implementation. [Maven - Available Plugins](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/index.html) actually shows it as "retired".

Comment: Do not define defaults like `<sourceDirectory>..</sourceDirectory>` and `<testSourceDirector>..</testSourceDirectory>` furthermore why do you need `-parameters` ? Apart from that using profiles for different environments is not a good idea better go like this: https://github.com/khmarbaise/multienv-maven-plugin/ BTW: You should always define all plugins you are using with their versions to be sure you will always using the same versions of plugin. For example I'm missing maven-war-plugin, maven-resources-plugin etc.

Comment: Hi, @khmarbaise! The `-parameters` were added to fix some parameters bug that I can't remember exactly. I chose to use the defaults because I might need to change then in the future and not forget the tag name. Your plugin looks nice, but my pom seems to be almost 100% setup (only missing the web services part).